# Powershell: Formatting executable

Tags: string, powershell, formatting

I'm trying to create a script that will format the output of w32tm.exe /monitor and display in a table the server name, NTP offset, and RefID.

I'm a little unaware of how to go about getting the output from an executable file to format it and was wondering if someone here could help me. Right now I'm trying this:

```
$executable = w32tm.exe /monitor
$executable | Format-Table -View "Server Name", "NTP offset", "RefID"
```

How can I manage to get the executable to be formatted in a table to display those specific parts of the exe?

Comment: Read here http://www.kylesulik.com/2011/06/ntp-time-monitoring/ . It can help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query domain controllers & NTP servers time w32tm /monitor format output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798009/query-domain-controllers-ntp-servers-time-w32tm-monitor-format-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I also needed to do this before I found a function someone made to do this have a look I am sure you can change it to suit your needs or just use it as is .

[ps-function](http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/2012/01/convert-text-to-object-updated/)

[Article on how it works](http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/2011/10/turning-cli-tools-into-powershell-tools-deep-dive-demos/)