# Running w32tm and assigning result to variable gives different output

Tags: powershell, time, batch-file, formatting, cmd

I am trying to follow the [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9802637/1142106) to parse the output of w32tm and arrange the items in an easy-to-read table of data. I noticed that I am getting un-ordered, incorrectly placed results in the different columns.

In testing, if i type this:

```
w32tm /monitor /domain:mydomain.com.au /Threads:5
```

I get each server ordered and formatted correctly, with it's NTP offset and ICMP delay appearing perfectly, like this:

```
kesvm001.mydomain.com.au[xxx.xxx.xxx.x:xxx]:
    ICMP: 37ms delay
    NTP: -0.0446479s offset from VM021.mydomain.com.au
        RefID: VM021.mydomain.com.au [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx]
        Stratum: 4
VM033.mydomain.com.au[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxx]:
    ICMP: 50ms delay
    NTP: -0.0640493s offset from VM021.mydomain.com.au
        RefID: 80.84.77.86.rev.sfr.net [xx.xx.xx.xx]
        Stratum: 2
```

If I then do this:

```
$output = & w32tm /monitor /domain:mydomain.com.au /Threads:5
$output
```

The only way I can explain what it does is that it seems to output ALL verbose information as well...

```
Getting AD DC list for mydomain.com.au
Analyzing:Analyzing:Analyzing:Analyzing:Analyzing:Analyzing:Analyzing:Analyzing:Analyzing:Analyzing:Analyzing:Analyzing:Analyzing:Analyzing:Analyzing:Analyzing:Analyzing:Analyzing:delayoffset from VM021.mydomain.com.au
Stratum: 4

  1  2 -- (0 of 48)
 11 12  3 (9 of 48)
 16 13 17 (14 of 48)
 21 18 20 (18 of 48)
 26 18 27 (24 of 48)
 26 18 28 (25 of 48)
 26 18 30 (27 of 48)
 26 18 31 (28 of 48)
 26 18 32 (29 of 48)
 26 18 32 (29 of 48)
 33 34 32 (31 of 48)
 39 40 41 (38 of 48)
 42 46 41 (43 of 48)
 42 -- 41 (46 of 48)
 -- -- 41 (47 of 48)
 -- -- 41 (47 of 48)
 -- -- 41 (47 of 48)
 -- -- 41 (47 of 48)




kesvm001.mydomain.com.au[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx]:
    ICMP: 37ms 
    NTP: -0.1127470s         RefID: VM021.mydomain.com.au [192.168.48.150]
        VM033.mydomain.com.au[xxx.xxx.xxdelayoffset from VM021.mydomain.com.au
Stratum: 2
delayoffset from VM021.mydomain.com.au
Stratum: 4
delayoffset from VM021.mydomain.com.au
Stratum: 3
delayoffset from VM021.mydomain.com.au
Stratum: 4
delayoffset from VM021.mydomain.com.au
Stratum: 4
delayoffset from VM021.mydomain.com.au
Stratum: 4
delayoffset from VM021.mydomain.com.au
Stratum: 4
delayoffset from VM021.mydomain.com.au
```

I thought it may be to do with using multiple threads, but even after changing Threads to 1 it makes no difference. What the hell is happening here? All i'm doing (I thought) was taking whatever output that normally appears on the screen, and placing it in a variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually does what it supposed to do. It is cathing all the output there was. If you will run it in the cmd console you will notice that before showing you result it's actually print out some progress information. When in PowerShell it catches everything. If you want to filter some stuff out you can do something like this:

```
$output = & w32tm /monitor /domain:mydomain.com /threads:5
$output | Where-Object{!$_.StartsWith("Analyzing") -and !$_.StartsWith("           ") -and !$_.Contains(" of ") -and !$_.StartsWith("Stratum") -and !$_.StartsWith("delayoffset")}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, thanks for this! Do you think there is anyway to simply capture what is eventually left on the screen (the 'final' output) as opposed to all the other progress information?

Comment: @ChristopherO'Neil Never heard about it. I think not